# Conducting rod moving through a uniform magnetic field Purcell

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

In Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism, Section 7.2, he talks about the field of a conducting rod moving through a uniform B-field. He then goes on to say the E-field and B-Field in the reference frame moving with the rod is related by E'=v x B'. In the previous chapter he mentioned that in the special case where in one reference frame E=0, then the field in the moving reference frame can be given by E'=v x B'. ***But***, the problem I am having is that in the frame where the rod is moving with velocity **v**, the electric field **is not zero** because the magnetic field causes the charges to separate in the rod and hence an electric field appears. So why is it that we can use E'=v x B'?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an opinion, but if you are in the rod reference frame your velocity say $v$ is zero, and therefore there's no electric field generated in the rod.